# opencart front page 403 forbidden - what should my nginx vhost file look like?

Tags: nginx, opencart

I've just setup Opencart with nginx as webserver but when I try to access `domain.com/` I get `403 Forbidden`, but if I access `domain.com/index.php` it works fine.

My nginx virtual host file looks like this (part of):

```
    location / {
            index index.html index.php index.htm;
            try_files $uri @opencart;
    }

    location @opencart {
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
```

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: in the error log, does it say directory listing forbidden ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this:

```
location / {
        index index.html index.php index.htm;
        try_files $uri @opencart;
}
```

To this:

```
location / {
        index index.html index.php index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
}
```

It now works.